# How to put 1 box within 2 filters at once - HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working with a filtering system through some JS on one of my pages, I don't exactly remember which version it is, but I know I got it off of codepen, and I'll include it below. I'd like to have some of the boxes be able to be filtered 2 different ways, for example, I'd like some boxes to be able to be filtered in either timelords or amelia2 (see below). I'm not sure how to do that, and I've been fiddling with it for a while, so a simple fix like doing < a class="amelia2 timelords" data-color="amelia2 timelords"> isn't working...... :(

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

CODE:
JS

```
< script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">< /script>
< script>
$(function($) {

  'use strict';

  var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
    $boxes = $('.boxes [data-color]');

  $filters.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    $filters.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    var $filterColor = $this.attr('data-filter');

    if ($filterColor == 'all') {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.filter('[data-color = "' + $filterColor + '"]')
            .addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
        });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
< /script>
```

CSS

```
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;

        }

        html {
            font: 15px/1.65 sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .filter {
            margin: 30px 0 10px;
        }

        .filter a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 2px solid rgba(42, 0, 48, 0.6);
            position: relative;
            top:145px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-top:-20px;
            background:rgba(239, 170, 248, 0.6);
            color:rgba(42, 0, 48, 0.6);
            font-size:20px;
            font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
            text-transform:lowercase;
        }

        .boxes {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .boxes a {
            width: 250px;
            height:500px;
            position:relative;
            top:150px;
            margin: -10px -130px 20px 165px;
            line-height: 60px;
            font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
            text-transform:lowercase;
        }


        .filter a.active:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 15px 15px 0 0;
            border-color: rgba(239, 170, 248, 0.6) transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        .is-animated {
            animation: .6s zoom-in;
        }

        @keyframes zoom-in {
            0% {
            transform: scale(.1);
        } 
        100% {
            transform: none;
        }
        }
```

HTML

```
< div class="cta filter" >
  < a class="all active" data-filter="all" href="#all" role="button" >All Muses< /a>
  < /br>
  < a class="timelords" data-filter="timelords" href="#timelords" role="button" >Time Lords/Ladies< /a>
   < a class="angels" data-filter="angels" href="#angels" role="button" >Angels< /a>
  < /br>
  < a class="amelia2" data-filter="amelia2" href="#amelia2" role="button">Amelia2< /a>
< a class="amelia3" data-filter="amelia3" href="#amelia3" role="button">Amelia3< /a>
< a class="james" data-filter="james" href="#james" role="button">James< /a>
< a class="rachel" data-filter="rachel" href="#rachel" role="button">Rachel< /a>
< a class="keegant" data-filter="keegant" href="#keegant" role="button">Keegan and T< /a>
< a class="jessica" data-filter="jessica" href="#jessica" role="button">Jessica< /a>
  < a class="henry" data-filter="henry" href="#henry" role="button">Henry< /a>
< a class="johnny" data-filter="johnny" href="#johnny" role="button">Johnny< /a>
< a class="dani" data-filter="dani" href="#dani" role="button">Dani< /a>
< a class="judy" data-filter="judy" href="#judy" role="button">Judy< /a>
< /div>
< div class="boxes" >

< a class="amelia2" data-color="amelia2" >
TEXT TEXT TEXT
< /a>
```

Comment: To add a new filter it sounds like you just need `<a class="amelia2" data-filter="amelia2 timelords">`. `<a class="amelia2 timelords" data-filter="amelia2">` simply adds a CSS class rather than a filter.

Comment: Thanks @ObsidianAge, but unfortunately that didn't work. When I tested it, the box the tried it on actually just didn't filter at all, and just always stayed there :(( I also tried < a class="amelia2" data-color="amelia2 timelords">, but that made neither filter work for that box :/